# is it possible to use AWS to run a regular windows 10 machine?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, windows-10

I want a Windows 10 x64 Professional hosted on AWS, is that possible? And if so, how might one go about it?

To expound. 
I just want a real windows 10 environment hosted remotely with static IP address so i can use it like a personal computer + server for some dev stuffs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is likely what you are looking for:

https://aws.amazon.com/workspaces/

> Amazon WorkSpaces is a managed, secure cloud desktop service. You can
>   use Amazon WorkSpaces to provision either Windows or Linux desktops in
>   just a few minutes and quickly scale to provide thousands of desktops
>   to workers across the globe. You can pay either monthly or hourly,
>   just for the WorkSpaces you launch, which helps you save money when
>   compared to traditional desktops and on-premises VDI solutions. Amazon
>   WorkSpaces helps you eliminate the complexity in managing hardware
>   inventory, OS versions and patches, and Virtual Desktop Infrastructure
>   (VDI), which helps simplify your desktop delivery strategy. With
>   Amazon WorkSpaces, your users get a fast, responsive desktop of their
>   choice that they can access anywhere, anytime, from any supported
>   device.

and this is how you can give it a static ip:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/associate-elastic-ip-workspace/

Edit:

> Amazon WorkSpaces now offers bundles that come **with a Windows 10
>   desktop experience, powered by Windows Server 2016**. Amazon WorkSpaces
>   Windows 10 bundles provides you an easy way to move users to a modern
>   operating system, while also simplifying licensing. Amazon WorkSpaces
>   continues to offer bundles that come with a Windows 7 desktop
>   experience, provided by Windows Server 2008 R2. **You can also run
>   Windows 7 and Windows 10 Enterprise operating systems with Amazon
>   WorkSpaces if your organization meets the licensing requirements set
>   by Microsoft.**

Comment: I tried firing up an AWS workspace thinking it would give me a Windows 10 workstation so that I could do some testing with Edge. It turned out to be a stripped down Windows Server 2016 instance.

Comment: Indeed, what AWS offers as Win10 is actually Server 2016, which is also quite old (no WSL for example). About BYOL read their FAQ, you can use it only if you're committing to keep 200 workspces running. Not exactly that common.

Answer (score 2):

@BrownChiLD 
You can create your own AMI on AWS. Steps are below:
1. create the machine on your system by using vmware wokrstation or hyper-v
2. Export the VM
3. Upload it to S3 bucket
once your vm is uploaded to S3, follow the steps on the below link
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html#import-vm-image

Answer (score 1):

At present time the only way to achieve what you want is by spinning your own Win10 instance assigning the static internal IP while creating it or by adding an Elastic IP if it's in an Internet Gateway enabled subnet.

It's not that convenient, you'll need to set up the environment yourself, including Security Groups, ACLs, etc to allow a bit of security and connecting using RDP will be a bit of a pain (beside doing so over internet isn't exactly advisable). You might start thinking about Chrome Remote Desktop or even Teamviewer.. and will be **very** pricey running it. First things first, apparently there's no Win10 available as AMI, so you'll need to deploy it yourself. Once running you'll need to license it. A type suitable for this could cost around 80$ per month.. unreserved.

**Using AWS Workspaces isn't really an option**: besides it is **not** "Windows 10" but Windows server 2016 (I needed WSL, which has been introduced with Server 2019 so, no joy), the only way to have a proper Win10 is using BYOL but... (cit from [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/workspaces/faqs/#BYOL)) :

> You need to commit to running **200** Amazon WorkSpaces in a region per month on hardware that is dedicated to you. If you want to bring your own Windows desktop licenses for graphics use cases, you need to commit to at least 4 monthly or 20 hourly GPU-enabled WorkSpaces.

:-/

Comment: Is there a way to load WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) into an AWS windows workspace? Doesn't seem to be, but it seems like something you may know.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon WorkSpaces is a virtual desktop that runs on AWS but you connect through an Amazon client software that acts a lot like virtualbox, except the OS that you're using is not on your local machine. So it's more like a Thin Client environment over the internet.  I believe the OS through Workspaces is managed by AWS as far as patching and updates through a software called A.C.M.E. (Amazon Client Management Engine).
https://youtu.be/jsqI7KU3S8I

Amazon EC2 instances also provide Windows instances that you would connect through an RDP connection. You'll have to manage the patching and updates yourself though.
Here's a link for your reading pleasure
https://aws.amazon.com/windows/resources/licensing/